# Testing File Updates and Improvements without showing to users

Tags: php, apache, web

I'm pretty new to web development and as I build websites using an Apache server, I was wondering how to prototype changes. For example, say I'm working on improving a PHP file that is already being displayed on the site. How can I test whether the changes I'm implementing work when the updated file is put on the server without disrupting users to the site if there is an error in the new code?

Comment: you could work with a copy; if everything's ok, then overwrite the one(s) in question; that's one way

Comment: But to test whether the copy works with other elements of the server (files saved in the server, other php files being served, etc.), wouldn't a copy still be served to users?

Comment: Not unless what you're trying to test isn't the main file and is an included file, without having to change everything.

Comment: again; work with copies of all your files; that's what I do and run it under another folder if you have to. Question is starting to be too broad and rather unclear, IMHO. If you're working with a db; make a copy of it.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you

Comment: there are other ways though and blocking all traffic except your own being another way. There are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a local copy of your site on your machine where you can test your codes, if that works, add it to your live website, Simple!

Comment: yeah, I said that in comments already. This could even be deeper than you/I think.

Comment: What if it needs to reference information saved elsewhere on the server, so that it isn't possible to test locally?

Comment: you can simply change the paths bro.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  why you didn't answer & only commented if that's the only solution? just asking.

Comment: you figure they would have invited me to *lol* - I told them there were other options they can use, I found the question too broad, IMHO.